# My website uses Twitter Bootstrap and crashes on IE 10 - Dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

Yeah; that's all the info I have; so my website seems to be crashing only in IE10 (it completely blocks the browser) and I can't find the reason; it works fine on Chrome and Firefox. The site is "responsive".

I wish I had more info but truly that's all I have and IE10 doesn't show me anything in the console before crashing.

Here is a [link to the 'main' JS file](http://programando.la/js/app.js?nocahe=1).

**Edit:** Fixed the problem; I was creating a new `<img>` tag and also trying to use the "load" event on such image every time I was executing a function and IE10 doesn't seem to like that; apparently other browsers immediately just check if the image is already loaded but IE10 seems to do it asynchronously resulting in some kind of stack-overflow.

Comment: What does "crash" mean here?

Comment: IE10 landed on Win7 today so you could test it there if you've got Win7 though it'll likely work on one test environment aond not another... Can you install a VM or test remotely with http://www.modern.ie/en-US ? EDIT: does it crash on Metro UI, the normal one or both?

Comment: Crash means absolute proccess crash; the IE proccess stops responding and I have to use the "Window Task Manager" to close it .

I forgot to mention that it passes the Modern.ie tests.

I am using it only on Windows 7 since months ago, the current version is 10.0.9200

Comment: Note: Your link to JS points to the same CSS as above

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: For the people voting to close the question: It would be more useful to change the wording to be more descriptive about this problem Internet Explorer haves instead of just closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas...

In my IE10 the site crashes, too. But I managed to start the DevTools and there the script console and Breakpoints.

At first it broke here:

```
return typeof v=="undefined"||!!e&&.event.triggered===e.type?t:v.event.dispatch.apply(u.elem,arguments)
```

(but it's a big codeblock, I don't understand it)
and then here:

```
(function loop(loading) 
{
  if (waitForHold) 
  {
    setTimeout(loop, 5000);
    return;
  }
...
```

in app.js - maybe here's a loophole which occurs only in IE10.

Comment: Thanks for the response; going to check it out in a moment.

Comment: I was creating an <img> tag inside the loop and then using the "load" event and IE10 apparently doesn't like that; so yeah; it was some type of loophole.